# Select features matching the values in an array (QGIS 3.10 expression)

Tags: qgis, expression, array

I want to use an expression to select features matching the values of an array.

Select features from a list is done by the IN operator:

```
"field" IN ('value1','value2')
```

But how to select features from an array like ['value1','value2']? Do I have to convert it to a list (somehow) or is there a "direct" method of doing so?

QGIS 3.10

Comment: `array_find(['value1','value2'], "field") <> -1` returns `0` (True) if field in array.

Comment: You can also use array_contrains.
array_contains(array(5,7,9),5) = True returns 1 (True)                                                         array_contains(array(5,7,9),6) = True returns 0 (False)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression builder has a whole section of functions for dealing with arrays.

> `array`   Returns an array containing all the values passed as parameter
>
> `array_append`    Returns an array with the given value added at the end
>
> `array_cat`   Returns an array containing all the given arrays concatenated
>
> `array_contains`  Returns true if an array contains the given value
>
> `array_distinct`  Returns an array containing distinct values of the given array
>
> `array_filter`    Returns an array with only the items for which an expression evaluates to true
>
> `array_find`  Returns the index (0 for the first one) of a value within an array. Returns -1 if the value is not found.
>
> `array_first` Returns the first value of an array
>
> `array_foreach`   Returns an array with the given expression evaluated on each item
>
> `array_get`   Returns the Nth value (0 for the first one) of an array
>
> `array_insert`    Returns an array with the given value added at the given position
>
> `array_intersect` Returns true if any element of array_1 exists in array_2
>
> `array_last`  Returns the last element of an array
>
> `array_length`    Returns the number of elements of an array
>
> `array_prepend`   Returns an array with the given value added at the beginning
>
> `array_remove_all`    Returns an array with all the entries of the given value removed
>
> `array_remove_at` Returns an array with the given index removed
>
> `array_reverse`   Returns the given array with array values in reversed order
>
> `array_slice` Returns the values of the array from the start_pos argument up to and including the end_pos argument
>
> `array_to_string` Concatenates array elements into a string separated by
>   a delimiter and using optional string for empty values
>
> `generate_series` Creates an array containing a sequence of numbers
>
> `regexp_matches`  Returns an array of all strings captured by capturing groups, in the order the groups themselves appear in the supplied regular expression against a string
>
> `string_to_array` Splits string into an array using supplied delimiter and optional string for empty values

(Source: [QGIS User Manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#array-functions))

Use `array_contains(your_array, "field")` to test whether your array contains the current field value.