# QGIS virtual layer SQL Query Arrays

Tags: qgis, sql, query

I have a polygon layer (A) with a field containing the farmers that use that polygon (the UUID of each farmer):

[image]

In each polygon feature can work from one to several farmers as it can be seen in the capture (2 farmers in 5 blue marked features and 6 farmers in 2 red marked features).
I want to create a virtual layer in which each farmer appears individually with its geometry (obtaining duplicated geometries, or even 6 polygons overlapped as in the example) and others attributes of the polygon layer (A) that I omit here.
I use this code:

```
select 
    UUID_Ganaderos,
    st_union(a.geometry) as geometry
from 
    A
group by UUID_Ganaderos
```

And got a dissolved (by farmer) layer (B) with the same farmers still together without duplicated geometries.
I tried adding some functions from this post [Select features matching the values in an array (QGIS 3.10 expression)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344412/select-features-matching-the-values-in-an-array-qgis-3-10-expression), but I don't know if the source field of farmers is an array (it came from a aggregate-concatenate expression without defining a "concatenator") or I have to tell the query that it's an array (first time trying to work with arrays).
I also tried creating a second virtual layer (C) asking the first (B) with the next code:

```
select  array(a.UUID_Ganaderos), 
        st_union(geometry) as geometry 
from 
    B, 
    D
where array_contains(B.UUID_Ganaderos,D.UUID_Ganaderos)
group by D.UUID_Ganaderos
```

Where D is a table with the unique list of farmers. I tried this with several combinations of *array* functions, but nothing works. I get errors or empty tables.
How can I obtain a virtual layer with one polygon for each farmer using the UUID field I have in layer A?

EDIT: I wanted to add 2 tables (A with the polygons and D with the farmers as in the original post), but don't know how to attach a file that is not an image, so I attach an image of the shapes and the attribute tables. I simplified them so we can speak with numbers and not UUIDs.
[image]
There are 4 features (polygons). Two of them (Farms Nº2 and 3) single farmed (farmers 7 and 8). Another (farm Nº1) with 2 farmers (8 and 9). And the last one (farm Nº4) with 6 farmers that share all the area (farmers from 1 to 6).
I want the query with 9 features (polygons):

- One with farm Nº2 for farmer 7.
- One polygon (multi) that comprises farms Nº1 and 3 for farmer 8.
- One polygon with farm Nº1 for farmer 9. This polygon will be overlapped with the previous one (farm Nº1).
- One polygon of farm Nº4 for each farmer from 1 to 6 (these 6 polygons will be overlapped)
  The table D only has the UUIDs (from 1 to 9 in the layers attached) of the farmers to use with the *group_by* statement.

Comment: Can you share a piece of your data with us?

Comment: Done, if I discover how to attach a gpkg with the shapes of the example, I'll do that too.